# How to share code between native C++ (Windows 7 and previous) and universal C++ (Windows 8 and later) apps

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-runtime, code-reuse

What are effective code-sharing/code-reuse practices or other development gotchas one should be aware of when developing a standard native C++ desktop application for Windows 7 (and earlier) with the intent of providing a side-by-side Windows 8 (and later) version of the application ([universal C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974580.aspx) and/or [Windows Store-friendly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160316.aspx), if those aren't the same thing) in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with windows desktop apps (using Win32, .net, etc on Win8 and Win7) compared to windows store app (based on WinRT/XAML, only Win8) is the different approach regarding UI.  One solution would be to isolate UI related functions.

Article *[Windows store apps using C++ and XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160326.aspx)* recommends this architecture:

> When possible, use C++11 and the standard C++ libraries (for example,
>   the STL and CRT) for your **core app logic** and the C++/CX syntax only at
>   the boundary where you **interact** with the [Windows Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime).

If you follow this recommendation, you'll be able to share a lot of code between the two (business/back office logice) as well as common utility functions.

One way to achieve this:

> Use the pimpl idiom ("pointer to implementation") to hide
>   implementation, minimize coupling, and separate interfaces. ...
>   implementation details to a .cpp ... a smart pointer to that
>   implementation in the private section of the class declaration in the
>   .h.

So all your platform specific objects would be regrouped in an implementation object, and your common code could remain platform independent.

Comment: Thanks-- we are using PIMPL throughout and the system is pretty well decoupled so this looks like a solid approach.